# Xamarin animations started glitching

Tags: android, animation, xamarin, imageview

I have animated an `ImageView` to rotate in one of my `Activity`s. It was working fine, but after some changes (I think it was Xamarin update), all animated images are now glitchy (google "glitch effect" to get the idea).

Here's the animation xml just in case:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
 <rotate
  android:duration="20000"
  android:fromDegrees="0"
  android:pivotX="50%"
  android:pivotY="50%"
  android:repeatMode="restart"
  android:repeatCount="infinite"
  android:toDegrees="359" />
</set>
```

Comment: My Xamarin version is 4.5.0.476 and it works fine. How did you start  the animation ?

Comment: I just use .StartAnimation(anim);

Comment: Could you share a simple demo of your code? I cant reproduce your problem.

Comment: @York Shen  var anim = AnimationUtils.LoadAnimation(this, Resource.Animation.rotate);
            FindViewById(Resource.Id.DiscoveredGenderShine).StartAnimation(anim);

Comment: Could you share a sample of your project? It will useful for me to find a solution. : )